# Cron Job status always missed/ not running Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

So I have a magento 2 instance running on ubuntu and I have some confusion about cron jobs. I know that magento 2 needs to have scheduled jobs in order to work correctly, but I am unable to find out how to get it set up correctly. I have read the dev docs, and followed this [article](https://amasty.com/blog/magento-2-cron-job-starter-guide/). Currently, I'm not getting any errors I can see on the magento side, but I'm having issues with things changing correctly (i.e. changing menu options/product options). I have also changed the Missed if Not Run Within field to be longer than the jobs per [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-2-3-Cron-job-won-t-run-Status-is-missed-One-is-stuck/td-p/117339) The cron_schedule table has all statuses as missed. I am not trying to do any custom jobs, just whatever default ones it needs to operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands from your Magento directory:

```
php bin/magento cron:install

php bin/magento cron:run
```

and check if all jobs are running by schedule.

Comment: I haven't ran the install command, Let me try that. How do I check if all jobs running by schedule? Is that an option in the admin side or in the database? Thansk

Comment: I ran both these commands, and in the backend of magento all the indexes say on schedule. However, the database is still saying missed.

Answer (score 1):

Any custom extension installed?
If not then please truncate Cron tables and check once by running default Magento Cron command.

Comment: There is a theme, but no extensions. What does truncate the tables mean? Thanks

Comment: Truncate means just flush existing CRON entries.
Query: "TRUNCATE cron_schedule"

Comment: TRUNCATE cron_schedule Yes like this

Comment: Would appreciate your input. Does truncating the table mean the jobs will be missed, or would they  re-populate and get executed?